Hyper-V Get-VM output language
So I've roamed stackoverflow searching for a good answers, but none worked.
I'm trying to get Hyper-V VM status in a script using Get-VM powershell scriptlet.
Example to get the first VM status (Get-VM)[0].Status
My problem is that using a french localized server, the result is Fonctionnement normal which translates to Ok.
When doing operations like merging disks, I get Fusion des disques instead of MergingDisks.
Of course, I would like my script to work regardless of the current language.
I've tried numerous ways to change Powershell language for current session (tried Temporarily change powershell language to English?, and Forcing PowerShell errors output in English on localized systems and others) of which none worked for me.
Is there anything I can do to force Get-VM (and other commands) to ouput english language, or perhaps just output integers which map to the corresponding string ?
My env:
Windows 2019 x64 with PSVersion 5.1.17763.6414
[EDIT]
I've tried to work with enums, so far without success.
On given system, I can get the possible VM Status (non localized english) with [enum]::GetNames([Microsoft.HyperV.Powershell.VMOperationalStatus]) whereas Get-VM will spit localized output.
I've managed to get the conversions from and to enum objects to ints, but it doesn't help any further:
Transforming "Ok" string into int (value 2)
[int][Microsoft.HyperV.Powershell.VMOperationalStatus]::"Ok"

Transforming int 2 into "Ok" string:
[Enum]::ToObject([Microsoft.HyperV.Powershell.VMOperationalStatus], 2)

My problem seems that (Get-VM)[0].Status doesn't actually return an enum, but a plain string, which of course is localized (eg Fonctionnement Normal instead of Ok) so I cannot use neither of above functions for conversions.
I didn't find any solution yet.
[/EDIT]

For a work-around: run Powershell in a system that's fully English. Most management cmdlets support remote targets.

I'd guess that it's an enum type so try something like (an example for another type) [enum]::GetValues([System.Security.PolicyLevelType])| ForEach-Object {@{$_ = [int]$_}}. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462344 for further info about Microsoft.HyperV.Powershell namespace…

@JosefZ So [enum]::GetNames([Microsoft.HyperV.Powershell.VMOperationalStatus]) gives the english strings of (Get-VM)[0].Status, but I'd still need to convert both Get-VM output and enum output to int to compare. Also, your link is dead.

Try [Microsoft.HyperV.Powershell.VMOperationalStatus]::$((Get-VM)[0].Status).value__?

Returns nothing, but doesn't throw an error. I've tried without .value__ and with | fl, nothing is returned. I've edited my answer with more info.

I think you need to use the Parse Method.  Here is the code I use in c# : VMOperationalStatus vm = (VMOperationalStatus)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(VMOperationalStatus), "Ok");

@jdweng That's basically what I do with [int][Microsoft.HyperV.Powershell.VMOperationalStatus]::"Ok". The thing is that I don't get "OK" but a localized version, which isn't even an enum, but a simple string.

You said "Transforming "Ok" string into int" which is what the parse method does.  What you do does not work.  You have double quotes "Ok" and you code would only work without the double quotes.

Not sure we understood each other. I can transform Ok into int and vice-versa, but what Get-VM gives me is the localized version Fonctionnement Normal, which is a litteral string which I can't convert since the enum types have non localized strings.

Try following : enum VMOperationalStatus {
Ok = 2
};
$results = [VMOperationalStatus][System.Enum]::Parse([VMOperationalStatus],"Ok"); [int]$results
